# Javascript: Unable to load image resource on a div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Can anyone please give me an idea on how to view the actual image resource on a div tag:

This is the complete script:

```js
var smileys = [];
smileys[":)"] = "happy.png";
smileys[":D"] = "laugh.png";
smileys[":3"] = "meow.png";
smileys[":{"] = "must.png";
smileys[":V"] = "pac.png";
smileys[":("] = "sad.png";
smileys[":O"] = "surprised.png";
smileys[":?"] = "wat.png";

function RegExpEscape(str) {
  return str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
}

function replaceEmoticons(str) {
  for (var key in smileys) {
    var re = new RegExp("(?:^|\\s)" + RegExpEscape(key) + "(?=$|\\s)", 'g');
    var str2 = "<img src='images/smileys/" + smileys[key] + "'/>";
    //alert(re);
    //alert(str2);
    var inputName = document.getElementById("input");
    alert(inputName);
    str = str.html().replace(re, str2);
  }
  return (str);
}

var delay = (function() {
  var timer = 0;
  return function(callback, ms) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
  };
})();

update();

function update() {
  $('#result').text(replaceEmoticons($('#input').val()));
}

$('#input').keyup(function() {
  delay(update, 250);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h4>Input :</h4>

<textarea id="input">
  Hello how are you all doing today? :)
</textarea>

<hr>
<h4>Result :</h4>

<div id="result">
</div>
```

When I inspect element no error was found on the console!
Kindly Assist!

Comment: Unless you've defined somewhere else in your script a method `.html()` on `String.prototype` this line `str = str.html().replace(re, str2);` won't work!

Answer (score 1):

Note that the javascript code is executing before the DOM is loaded. When you load page, after loading the code is executing and #input doesn't exist yet. Put it in a $(document).ready, or in a onload event.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

      //your stuff

 });
```

## EDIT

See that fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aoaugpaf/

Comment: Nice one Marcos, Is there a way I can load the actual .png on the textarea instead of the file path!

Comment: In a textarea you can't load any resource, only plain text. If you want to do a WYSIWYG editor, you must to try with a layer above the textarea. If I  help you please, upvote my answer.

Comment: I equally tried a div and it is still returning the file path. Does that mean I cant create my own custom emoticons.

Comment: Can you give me an example of the layer you are talking about for me to research on. Had upvoted your answer but its like I need 15 reputations. Regards.

Comment: If you search in google you can find several articles in your language and in english. In a second, I find this: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-does-a-jquery-wysiwyg-editor-work . You only need to read how does it works and you can make your own code. I recommend you to use a finished wysiwyg editor instead of develop your one only to display emoticons.

Comment: Please, see that fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/aoaugpaf/ It's running like you need

Comment: Hi Marcos on running my initial script using  this>>>>>> <div id="result"> </div>  does not return the image. As edited on jsfiddle

Comment: @PatrickNdu It returns a broken image, because the path `img/smile.png` does not exist on JSFiddle servers....

Comment: That's is not issue Jamie, If I modify my original script it returns the actual path. At this point <div id="result"> </div> instead of  <textarea id="result"></textarea>

Comment: You are replacing with `text()` function, change it to `html()` function and it works. `$('#result').html(replaceEmoticons($('#input').val()));`

Comment: Hi Marcos: You are just a javascript expert! Please send me your facebook ID or email.

Comment: I haven't facebook, sorry :(

Comment: Okay no Probs! Let me see if I can use this opportunity to seek your advice one more time . Is there a way I can cluster the contents of "to view page source" on browsers when a user right clicks to view it using javascript may be with Bootsrap.js Regards!

Comment: You need to open a new post, but if you try to avoid users to view your code in client side is impossible. The only way to hide pieces of code to users is processing in server and return only the result.

Comment: Can you show me on jsfiddle or a code snippet or an area to research on. Hw do I actually hide the pieces of codes from users. Regards

Comment: Server's side you need another technology, javascript is a client-side technology. I can't show you a code because I don't know how do you need. Please, open new post with good explanation that you need and put here the URL to advice me.

Comment: This is the url Marcos>>>>>: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31243679/server-side-processing-to-cluster-the-content-or-prevent-the-content-of-view-p

Answer (score 0):

In this function:

```
 function replaceEmoticons(str) {
        for (var key in smileys) {
            var re = new RegExp("(?:^|\\s)" + RegExpEscape(key) + "(?=$|\\s)", 'g');
            var str2 = "<img src='images/smileys/" + smileys[key] + "'/>";
            //alert(re);
            //alert(str2);
            var inputName = document.getElementById("input");
            alert(inputName);
            str = str.html().replace(re, str2);
        }
        return (str);
    }
```

`str` doesn't have an `html()` method since it's the value of an input as you wrote here:

```
 $('#result').text(replaceEmoticons($('#input').val()));
```

Simply remove the `html()` method and everything will work.

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/f6e73grt/) a fiddle I've made for you.

Comment: Hi Amir : Can you use this >>>>>> <div id="result">
    </div> instead of this >>>>> <textarea id="result"></textarea> to see if you can view the image instead of the file path. Regards

Comment: Patrick Ndu, I tell you that in a textarea you don't see images or other html tags. only plain text. No matter what browser, O.S. or device you use.

Answer (score 0):

Because $().val() returns String and string has no method .html()

Edit function replaceEmoticons:

```
 str = str.replace(re, str2);
```

It works: http://jsfiddle.net/au419fkh/