# Server Side Processing to Cluster the content (or prevent the content) of View Page Source on Browser

Tags: javascript

I have a simple website with some basic scripts just like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to my website but a user can view page source --oops</title>
<script>
//some basic javascript codes i used to build the website
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>More contents on the actual implementation of the website.<p>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way I can use server side processing technique to cluster the contents of view page source as I have tried using javascript bt no substantial outcome. Please assist!

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide javascript, html, or css from users. You can proccess out in server like php some code but you need to return html. The only way to complicate user's reading of your code, you try minimize javascript/css/html code. YUI compressor can help you:

http://refresh-sf.com

This makes your code more difficult to read, but the behaviour is the same.

Good luck.

Comment: So how do I minimize javascript/css/html code. Regards

Comment: Visit the link that I shared with you, paste your javascript code in the textarea and copy the minimized result. You will see that the code is not legible.

Comment: You can use it to compress CSS, HTML and Javascript code, but in separately files.

Comment: I keep getting this error:{
  "message": "Unexpected token: operator (<)",
  "filename": "?",
  "line": 1,
  "col": 0,
  "pos": 0
}

Comment: Are you attempting to minimize html with javascript mode on? Please, read documentation or pay more attention in that you make.

Comment: Not at all Javascript mode is on!

Comment: I can't see that you are making. Note that the javascript code will be minimized if is good-writted code, and if you select javascript option. The same in html or css.

Comment: Thanks! You are awesome. Please send me your mail. Will like to have you as a tech friend!

Comment: How I send you my mail? I don't want to publish my email in a forum.

Comment: Just send me an email. Please

Comment: Ok, I recommend you to delete your email now